# Python hypergraph design / engines for hashtag relationships

Tags: python-3.x, graph, hypergraph

I started out using orientdb/pyorient to store hashtags and what hashtags they were related to. I got the point where I was storing the hashtags and then I needed to create the edges. I then realized that to do this, there would be a lot of redundant data. Each tag would have to be stored again as an edge to each tag it's related to.

I then discovered hypergraphs. I have found [halp](http://murali-group.github.io/halp/) which seems more standalone than something like orientdb. I don't think it has storage either. My question is, are there any well supported graph engines that can make these relationships without storing redundant data and have a python library?

Comment: It is not ready yet, but [CHGL](https://github.com/pnnl/chgl) is designed to work nicely with [Arkouda](https://github.com/mhmerrill/arkouda) which will add a Python layer.  I'm still looking for a similar tool.

Comment: @BrianDolan The perfect thing is Gundb. There's a Python wrapper but it's kinda lame as it uses a socket to talk to gun. A proper port of Gun to Python would be awesome. I've been trying to transpile. Haven't succeeded yet.